# Computational complexity of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the computational complexity of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm?

Suppose a matrix of `m` rows and `k` columns, how many operations are required to compute the orthogonalization?

If possible I would like to have the exact number of multiplications and additions.

EDIT:
It seems to me that the total number of operations (multiplication + additions) is `3/2k^2m + 3/2mk +k^2/2 +k/2`.
I would like to know if this is correct and if there is a quicker version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dot product takes m-1 additions and m multiplies.

Vector normalization takes 1 vector square (dot product), 1 square root and m divisions i.e.

```
m-1 +, m *, m /, 1 √
```

Subtraction of a vector projection takes 1 dot product, m multiplies and m additions, i.e.

```
2m-1 +, 2m *
```

Computation of the j-th vector takes (j-1) subtractions of projections, followed by a normalization, i.e.

```
(2m-1)(j-1)+m-1 +, 2m(j-1)+m *, m /, 1 √
```

You compute vectors from j=1 to k, so the factors (j-1) become the *triangular number* (k-1)k/2 and the terms independent of j are multiplied by k:

```
(2m-1)(k-1)k/2+(m-1)k +, 2m(k-1)k/2+mk *, mk /, k √
```

In the dot product, the m divisions can be traded for m multiplies by the inverse, yielding

```
(2m-1)(k-1)k/2+(m-1)k +, 2m(k-1)k/2+2mk *, k /, k √
```

So essentially 2mk² operations.

Comment: Nice precision with the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

The overall complexity of Gram-Schmidt algorithm is O(m.k^2):

The process must be applied k times and each orthogonalization takes O(m.k) opérations (multiplications and additions) so altogether it makes O(m.k^2) complexity

Comment: Do you know the total number of floats operations?

Comment: @Donbeo According to wikipedia, "The cost of this algorithm is asymptotically 2nk^2 floating point operations, where n is the dimensionality of the vectors." They cite Golub, Gene H.; Van Loan, Charles F. (1996), Matrix Computations (3rd ed.), Johns Hopkins, ISBN 978-0-8018-5414-9.

Comment: @Donbeo: Total number of floats operations not sure but you have to count multiplications as they are more relevant and in your formula you should ignore terms other than in m.k^2. I don't think you can do better with standard Gram-Schmidt Algorithm.

Comment: In PFUs, it is not so obvious that multiplies dominate additions.

Comment: Yes it can happen but why are you thinking so here ?

Comment: In Gram-Schmidt there are about as many additions as multiplies, there is no reason to ignore additions.

Comment: It's known that multiplications cost more in terms of calculation time and  additions are often ignored in Computational Complexity evaluation faced to mults. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

Comment: This link is not relevant, it relates to operations on `n` digits numbers. Here were are using floating-point representations and both additions and multiplication are O(1), multiplication being slightly slower.

Comment: yes you are right after checking not big difference for floating point ops